# How to create new folder in wp-content root same like upload folder?

Tags: directory, uploads

My query is how to create new folder `wp-content/any-folder-name` using code when the plugin is activated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The simple reason is that `wp-content` doesn't even have to exist, and if it exists, it might not be writable.

On systems with an automatic deployment and rollbacks, the upload directory is usually completely separated from the WordPress directory, and you cannot create a new directory on the same level.

Summary: If you need a writable directory, you *have* to use one inside of the existing upload directory. That's the only place where you can expect write access.

Comment: Still I have give full permission of **wp-content** directory and in other plugin give way to create folder when it is activated.