# Should custom directories be created under the wp-content directory?

Tags: directory

Another [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266667/how-to-create-new-folder-in-wp-content-root-same-like-upload-folder#) asks about creating a custom directory under the `wp-content` directory.

If there is a need for custom files e.g. CSS that need to be called, should a custom directory e.g. `css` be created under `wp-content` e.g. `wp-content/css`?

The function `wp_upload_dir()` returns the path to the `wp-content/uploads` directory and there doesn't appear to be a function to only return the path to `wp-content`.

Does this mean that custom directories such as the `css` directory should be created under `wp-content/uploads` instead?

An [article](https://themes.artbees.net/blog/add-external-css-or-javascript-to-wordpress/) on adding CSS or JavaScript resources suggests uploading these to the root of the child theme directory. What if there are other custom assets e.g. fonts?

In contrast another [article](https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/wordpress-file-structure/) recommends creating a sub-directory in the root directory e.g. `public_html/subdirectory`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "opinion based" - there is no definitive rule here. However, each of the suggested methods has various implications and might not work in every case. For files uploaded by users I'd always go for _wp-content/uploads/_ - for files shipped with the extension I'd always go for the (child) theme / plugin itself.

Comment: IMO this is an anti-pattern and a poor idea. It's extremely rare that this is necessary, and would depend on edge cases and the context. Generally it is not a good idea to mess with the WP folder structure beyond a subfolder install ( a separate WP Content folder and WP folder, which simplifies WP installs that use `git` or package managers to install and WP by avoiding nested folders ). Sadly, you will get mainly subjective answers to this, there is no canonical _"correct"_ answer to fit all situations

Comment: @kero - I'm unsure why it would be opinion base. Even though there is no definitive rule. I'm assuming that with the collective knowledge of WordPress experts, there would be recommendations. The use case examples I have are, when using third-party libraries e.g. bootstrap, lozad, etc that are enqueued using the a child-theme `functions.php`. These are not installed or deployed using plugins.

Comment: @TomJNowell - The context is using third-party libraries such as bootstrap, lozad and localized fonts (that are not packaged with WordPress core or the theme). Since I don't want to be introducing a change that may be disruptive to the native directory hierarchy, I'm seeking guidance as to the best practice (even if there isn't a canonical answer).

Comment: Like a `vendor` or `node_modules` folder? If they're not packaged with core or a theme then that means they were packaged with a plugin right? Or are you refusing to bundle your themes assets with the theme? Kero think it's opinion based because any answer you got would just be that persons opinion. Specific examples would make your question easier to answer and less opinionated, it's a little open ended which is usually bad for stack exchange questions. What lead you to ask this question? What did you intend to do with the result? The best practice advice on how to do this is: _it depends_

Comment: Try to narrow your question down with examples. For example if your goal is a `wp-content/vendor` folder for composer then I might have some advice. If the goal is a  `wp-content/bootstrap` folder then I would make every effort to steer you away from it. The questions scope is too wide ranging, and while there are a few situations where it might make sense to create a folder, they are not as common as people might think, and usually have alternatives or were chosen to fit around constraints

Comment: Also, you may find it difficult to get a consensus out of people, there is no codified best practice here, though you may notice more experienced developers leaning in a particular direction of sticking to WP's folder structure

Comment: @TomJNowell - Thanks. I'm assuming that outside of the core, themes and plugins, assets can be introduced to be used with WordPress (I'm making an assumption as I'm hoping to lean on the expertise here and I don't claim to be one). The example you cited is a good scenario e.g. I wish to enqueue third-party libraries such as `bootstrap` or `lozad`.

Comment: @TomJNowell - This would be initiated and loaded via the `child theme`. As these files are localized, it would sensible for these to be in `functional` directories e.g. `wp-content/css/bootstrap`. If the recommendation is to keep away from this, what are the options/suggestions? I'm  happy to update the question to make this clearer if need be.

Comment: That is a very bad idea and you should not do it, your theme assets belong in your theme, it should be self contained. They should not be placed outside it in a dedicated folder, if you want to use a subfolder inside your theme ok, lots of people do that. You can refer to parent theme assets, your own assets, even remote assets, but don’t place a themes assets outside its folder

Comment: @TomJNowell - Thanks. Have I understood you correctly that the libraries should be placed in the same directory as the theme i.e. `wp-content/themes/{name_of_theme}/{child_theme}/css/bootstrap`? If yes, the libraries can then be called with the function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`?

Comment: A themes assets should be inside that themes folder, the same with plugins. Assets belonging to a theme should not be placed outside that themes folder. Also, child themes do not go inside the folders of parent themes. A theme that references files in a `wp-content/css` folder would be extremely unusual, would not be sellable in a marketplace, could not be uploaded or installed via WP CLI, composer, the web interface, etc, it would be highly impractical, to name a few reasons of many. It would be considered _extreme_ bad practice by most

Comment: @Ryan I have read the article you linked to and i found no such recommendation,  search for subfolder and could not see anywhere the place it recommended such an action. I believe you have misunderstood the context of certain paragraphs and assumed it was referring to `wp-content/` when it is actually referring too the theme folder. If you were correct and it did recommend `wp-content/css` then I would tell you to ignore everything that site says, that the advice was wildly inaccurate, and to treat the author with great suspicion. But the author has not said this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is a need for custom files e.g. CSS that need to be called, should a custom directory e.g. css be created under wp-content e.g. wp-content/css?

### No, *never*. You should not do this under any circumstances.

*And the article isn't recommending it either.*

A theme is a folder that contains the theme files, and can be packaged as a zip for distribution or installation. Updating it removes and replaces the theme with a new version, etc. Taking part of that theme and putting it in a new place fundamentally breaks this.

A themes assets belong inside the theme. A plugins assets belong in that plugin. That could mean in the folder, in subfolders, etc. The only exception is when a child theme uses assets in its parent theme. Doing otherwise would be considered negligent by most WordPress developers, and a major red flag to many employers.

A themes folder should contain everything. It should not reference or store assets in a custom folder under `wp-content`.

This goes for anything your theme needs that isn't included with WP core or a parent theme. JS, CSS, JSON, PNG, PHP, etc etc. You can require the use of a plugin for functionality, or use a parent theme, but don't place parts of your theme in subfolders outside the theme folder. Likewise with plugins.

#### What Are The Consequences?

Here is a partial list of consequences, though many more exist:

- it's no longer possible to package and distribute the theme, wether that's for customers or for internal use
- Your theme would immediately fail wp.org review, as well as the review of theme market places
- Automated tooling for testing and checking would no longer function correctly
- The theme upload page would no longer fully install your theme as it doesn't know about your custom folder
- Theme updates would no longer fully update your theme
- Multiple themes that do this would cause conflicts, particularly on Multisite installations
- Caching and optimisation plugins may break the assets you placed in the custom folder, or fail to pick them up

  - poorly built caching plugins may even use a `css` subfolder and overwite your work. A well built plugin would instead use the uploads folder ( you should not use the uploads folder for theme assets, this has security and practical consequences )
- your theme will break on some enterprise grade and managed hosting due to folder mapping tech that doesn't account for the custom folder
- certain CI deployment processes would need manual modification to account for the folders or they'll be stripped out on deployment
- Unexpected folders in `wp-content` imply that the site has been compromised
- Incompatibility with `composer`
- Incompatibility with WP CLI
- **What happens if another theme decides it wants to use `wp-content/css` just like yours?**

#### What About Subfolders Inside My Themes Folder?

Inside your theme you can organise assets however you want, it's up to you. Put them in the root, put them in subfolders, it's your choice and there is no required location for theme sub-folder structure.

The only CSS file that needs a specific location is `style.css` which must be in the root as WordPress looks for it to read the theme name etc. Likewise top level PHP templates and `functions.php` go in the root folder.

---

### When Might Custom Folders in `wp-content` Make Sense?

*They never make sense for theme developers.*

The only time I've seen custom non-standard folders used in the `wp-content` folder are as follows:

- `vendor` folders created by the `composer` tool for PHP dependencies
- subfolders for CI such as `.gitlab`, or `.github` if your site is in version control, that aren't used by WP or the site, but are a part of the development process
- folders required by hosting platforms, usually a sign of an unusual architecture at an enterprise level. A common example is when a hosting provider uses `plugins-mu` and provides a second folder for client mu plugins ( also a sign that it never occurred to them to load that code with a drop in file and let the client use `plugins-mu` )

You may find some caching plugins use a cache subfolder, but there's no reason this can't be moved under `uploads/`. This also applies to plugins that rebuild assets such as optimising CSS, files that if they're deleted could be recreated without any loss.

In general, good reasons to make new subfolders in `wp-content` are 1 in a billion, and almost always a sign that something has gone wrong in the development process. Those edge cases that are allowable have nothing to do with the running site or are part of unusual high end hosting setups

### Then Why Does The Article Recommend `wp-content/css`?

**It doesn't.**

> In contrast another article recommends creating a sub-directory in the root directory e.g. public_html/subdirectory

This article does not recommend this. You are mistaken. It recommends a subdirectory *of the themes folder*, not `wp-content`. E.g. `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/css`

### The TLDR

- Put your themes assets inside your theme
- Put your plugins assets inside your plugin
- Unless you absolutely require it and it is unavoidable, don't create non-standard folders in `wp-content`

  - It's very likely that you don't require it, consult with other WP devs, these situations are extremely rare
  - If you need it for a theme, something has gone horribly wrong

Comment: Should subdirectories be created under the child theme e.g. `wp-content/themes/child-theme/css`?

Comment: If you want to create subfolders inside your child theme you can do that, it is _entirely_ up to you and personal preference. Create them, don’t create them, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  there is no right answer for that

Comment: As a clarification why `should It should not reference or store assets in a custom folder under wp-content`? What are the implications/side effects?

Comment: lets say your theme was distributed in any meaningful way, the assumption everywhere is that a theme is self contained, which is the same for plugins, and lots of other packages in PHP/WordPress/Other CMS's/etc. even the assets you speak of come as singular packages. If you were to take a big chunk of your theme and place it in a subfolder as you describe, how would those files get there? The themes panel doesn't support moving files out of the theme, nor does any of the tooling. It would require users to manually move the files and create the folder, or for the theme to do it automatically

Comment: And if it did it automatically, why bother in the first place? It would fail on a lot of systems due to security measures, would get picked by various security software as suspicious, and it conveys zero benefits. And what if a second theme wants to do this? Now you have conflicts! And if the theme gets deleted or removed there's now folders left behind. What if your theme gets updated? WP will delete the folder then replace it with the new one, but it doesn't know about `wp-content/css`. Neither do a lot of plugins that might optimise it. Then there's caching rules that don't account for it

Comment: I didn't mention that none of the functions dedicated to helping you find the theme folder would no longer apply. This is by no means an exhaustive list. It's an ***awful*** idea. Entertaining it is a waste of your time, even for experimental purposes. Anybody who suggests it may be a good idea is either a liar or grossly misinformed, do not listen to them. I've reviewed 10's of millions of lines of WP code for enterprise grade sites, none of them did this, and if they did I would have rejected it and told them to do it again. ***Put your themes assets in your theme.***

Comment: To stress this further, this isn't me saying it's a poor practice that some people do, that it's ill advised, or that "it's best practice to do it another way". This is me saying categorically, do not do this, it is bad. As a longterm WP developer, I can safely say never do this, under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for an amazingly detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a directory within the `wp_content` directory.
For example you can create  `wp_content/css` as you have described for special cases only. However, using child theme for custom CSS files is advisable.

To access the wp_content directory, you can use the **`WP_CONTENT_URL`** constant. Example usage:

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style', WP_CONTENT_URL . '/css/style.css', array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );
```

Also, you can use the **`WP_CONTENT_DIR`** constant to access the files in custom directories in wp_content. To access the CSS file use:

```
include WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/css/style.css';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this the recommend practice? What alternative is there to the `WP_CONTENT_URL` constant if the output needs to return an absolute path e.g. `/home/public_html/wp-content`?